# debugging C with eclipse and cygwin

Tags: c, eclipse, cygwin

I am trying to debug the following C code with eclipse-Juno-CDT, and cygwin-gcc (cygwin version=1.7.16, gcc version=3.4.4, gdb version=7.5.50), on 64bit windows. The code works fine in normal mode. Initially debugger was not running, because the source file was not found. Then I searched around and added the path mapping information (from /cygdrive/c to C:\). Now it is running but with the following problems:

1. I have put a breakpoint before the "hello c 1" line, and  then single stepping. But nothing gets printed on the console.
2. after single stepping on the last line ("exit"), I get the error: "No source available for _cygwin_exit_return() at ..."

   ```
   // stdio.h and stdlib.h are included, but when I put a #include the code
   // they dont show up, so I deleted those lines in this code fragment.
   int main(void) {
        int a=10;
        int b=5; // breakpoint on this line, single step after this
        printf("hello c 1\n"); // these outputs are not printed in console
        // fflush(stdout);
        printf("A=%d, B=%d\n", a, b); // but debugger shows the correct values in data window
        // fflush(stdout);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS; // error on this line
   }
   ```

Added later: After some more debugging, I figured that even after the exit-error, if I do a "continue", then I am getting the lines on the console after the program terminates. So I added extra "fflush(stdout)" lines, and now I can see the outputs when they are being printed.

But how to fix the exit-error problem? Also, editing the file to add fflush to see debug outputs is a pain - is there a way to avoid this? Can somebody help me with this very basic problem, or point me to a place where the solution is given? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the console tab in your debugging perspective, click on the console icon on the top right corner of the tab and try switching the consoles to see if any of them have your output.

Comment: what do you mean by "switching consoles"? BTW, I read this advise in another document:  "The program input and output on Linux is redirected to the Eclipse console. This doesn't work for Windows because there is no support for GDB TTY." So does this mean that this is a known and unsolved problem?

Comment: BTW, I did a "continue" after the exit-error occured, and the lines came up on the screen. So then I added a "fflush(stdout)" after each printf line, and now the output is appearing on the console. Is there any way to avoid this overhead of editing the file just for printing debug information? Also, the exit-error is not yet solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While *logically* a C program begins at `int main()` and ends when that function returns, environments (like Windows or Cygwin) frequently add pre- and post-code, for initializing / breaking down memory management, opening / closing standard streams, and other such bookkeeping. An executable compiled with Cygwin, after returning from `int main()`, switches to a cleanup function `_cygwin_exit_return()`, provided by the Cygwin runtime - for which you don't have sources, so your debugger complains.

As for getting the output immediately, you could use an unbuffered output stream.

Option one, use `fprintf( stderr, ... )` (since `stderr` is by definition unbuffered). This, however, also affects the non-debugging behaviour of your program.

Option two:

```
int main()
{
// Using NDEBUG as also used by <assert.h>; feel free to use a different define
#ifndef NDEBUG
    // For debugging, set stdout to unbuffered
    setbuf( stdout, NULL );
#endif
    ....
```

Comment: But one more question: stdout is line buffered, and I am printing a '\n' at the end of each line, so it should print the line. So then why is the line getting printed in normal mode, and not in debug mode? Does gdb add one more layer of buffering?

Comment: @Rog: It *shouldn't* do that. I can't say I've come across this behaviour in GDB (then again, I usually redirect stdout when running GDB, because having the output screw up your terminal is a pain).

Comment: Maybe it is a cygwin implementation problem. But I didnt understand your comment about redirecting stdout when running gdb - you mean you see/watch outputs only in the data windows and not the printed outputs? Or do you keep a separate vi open on the redirected file output?

Comment: @Rog: No, I redirect the output to file and *don't* look at it (usually). If I have to pick up breakpoint debugging, that means logging has already failed at giving me the intel I'm looking for; i.e., it's mostly in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Back when I was learning multithreading I was curious if threads were any faster than processes, and iirc I had to fflush even stderr/stdout on windows.

Memories aside, you can wrap those printf() in a function that calls fflush, or call setvbuf() to disable buffering.

About the exit: "no source available" only means that a part of your program lacks the info for debugging, so it's not a real error -- unless you build cygwin yourself, I guess the cygwin dll is stripped of debug symbols. Or maybe you want to debug cygwin's exit()?

EDIT: crap, concurrent answers :)